# I am trying to implement Euler Maruyama algorithm in the European call option but every time i run the function something different comes out

Tags: r

This is the function that I am trying to implement for Euler Maruyama algorithm, but every time I run it a different result comes out.

```
set.seed(123)
EulerMaruyama<-function(S_0=100,K=100,sigma=0.25,t=0,T=1,r=0.02,n=10^4){
     dt = T-t # dt 
     st =  numeric(n+1)
  st[1] =  100 # initial value 
# em algorithm 
  for (i in 1:n) {
    st[i+1] = st[i] + (r*(st[i]*(dt)) )+ 
     ( (sigma*(st[i])*(dt) )   *  (sqrt(dt)*rnorm(1))) } 
 # evaluate call option 
  payoffs = pmax(st - K,0)*exp(-r*(T-t))
  Price   = mean(payoffs)
  SE      = sd(payoffs)/sqrt(n)
  alpha   = qnorm(1-0.05/2)
  Lower   = Price - alpha * SE
  Upper   = Price + alpha * SE
  RMSE    = var(payoffs)/sqrt(n)
  return(c(Price=Price,SE=SE,Lower=Lower,Upper=Upper,RMSE=RMSE))  
} 
EulerMaruyama(S_0=100,K=100,sigma=0.25,t=0,T=1,r=0.02,n=10^4)
```

Comment: Many financial algorithms these days are based on stochastic calculus. They are inherently random in their solutions (jst as the stock market has been shown to be.) You might need to run this 500 or 1000 times to get a better idea of the potential range of predictions under such conditions. I suspect that's what your parameter K is doing. Perhaps going to the Quant page would help you understand this better: https://quant.stackexchange.com/search?q=Euler+Maruyama

Comment: I get the same result each time I run it.  Maybe you are only calling `set.seed(123)` the first time?  If so, you'll get different results because the random inputs (from `rnorm(1)`) will be different each time, as @42- said.